# Visual Studio solution doesn't compile, but project does

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017

When I build or rebuild my solution I get the error:

> Error  CS2012  Cannot open 'C:\Users\myUserName\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\mySolutionFolder\myProjectFolder\obj\Debug\myExecutable.exe' for writing -- 'Access to the path 'C:\Users\myUserName\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\mySolutionFolder\myProjectFolder\obj\Debug\myExecutable.exe' is denied.'

However, when I build the project, it compiles fine. Once I build the project then a solution build doesn't throw any errors. I am running visual Studio 2017.

What I've tried (without success):

1. There is a second project in the solution, but I've unloaded it and it still errors.
2. I deleted the solution file and had visual studio create a new one.

Additional Info:
The error is somewhat random. Usually it errors out, but sometimes not. The odds of an error are reduced the longer I wait between a "Clean" and a rebuild. I have the same problem even when running in Administrator mode. I'm beginning to think it's a hard drive issue.

Comment: You can try to clean your solution.  That has happened to me a few times.  The process may also still be running.  -- use taskkill /IM:myExecutable.exe /F /T

Comment: Have you any third party plugins (reshaper, ...) or features like live unit testing enabled? If so, disable them stepwise and check if the problem is still there.

Comment: Check for `msbuild` or `dotnet` processes still running and try to end it.

Answer (score 3):

The application is still running.

\Debug\myExecutable.exe' is denied.' is telling you that you cant replace that because its currently open.

Open task manager and make sure that you end that process, and it should work fine after that.

This is usually what happens to me when I get that error.

Hope this helps

Comment: As a method of last resort: restart your computer. Sometimes an antivirus program will snatch a hook to that file and never let go of it. Highly annoying.

Comment: Denied access to a file doesn't strictly indicate the application is running.  It can also be permissions, or some process has the file locked for reading or writing.  It can also indicate drive failure.

Comment: @Amy, true but in that case I would expect it not to be in the default build folder under debug, although I've had that issue you describe when I've done integrations with winscp, but in any case tho, you are right, doesn't always mean its running.

Answer (score 0):

There is a file handle still open for myExecutable.exe. Probably because it is still running (check task manager/process explorer).

If that is not the case, you can try find out which process has has a handle open to said file:

1. get [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)
2. Press Ctrl-F to find handle
3. Enter myExecutable.exe and look for processes that have a handle to the file.